# Is the category of left exact functors abelian?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

Let us consider the category of left exact functors between two abelian categories. Is this category abelian?
My intuition is that it is not. Does someone have any counterexample ? Or any proof that I'm false?
I think that we will have problems with cokernels...

Comment: Just to record a bit of info, the left exact functors $A\to\mathbf{Ab}$ are complete and cocomplete when $A$ is small, because they're a reflective subcategory of all additive functors $A\to\mathbf{Ab}$. But I'm pretty sure the reflection is not exact and so it's not quite clear to me whether this category is abelian.

Comment: @KevinCarlson The category of left exact functors $A\to\mathbf{Ab}$ is abelian for $A$ a small abelian category. This is used in the proof of the Freyd-Mitchell embedding theorem. But the proofs I know of use properties of $\mathbf{Ab}$ that aren't true for a general abelian category. For example, the proof in Swan's "Algebraic $K$-theory" uses that the category of additive functors $A\to\mathbf{Ab}$ is cocomplete, well-powered and has injective envelopes.

Comment: @JeremyRickard It seems you can replace Ab with any Grothendieck category (Prop. 5 in the second chapter of Gabriel's Des Catégories Abéliennes) to get similar results, but yes, that proof also relies on the stated extra assumptions.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example where $\mathbf{Lex}(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$ fails to have cokernels in which $\mathcal{B}$ is not cocomplete. Presumably there are also examples where $\mathcal{B}$ fails to be a Grothendieck category in other ways.

Also, I'm far from convinced that there are not much simpler examples than this.

Let $R$ be a countable dimensional algebra over a field $k$, and let $\mathcal{A}$ be the category of (at most) countable dimensional $R$-modules. Let $\hat{\mathcal{B}}$ be the category of vector spaces over $k$, and $\mathcal{B}$ the subcategory of (at most) countable dimensional vector spaces.

Note that if $X$ is a finitely generated $R$-module then it is an object of $\mathcal{A}$ and $\text{Hom}_R(X,-)$ is an object of $\mathbf{Lex}(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$.

If $0\to X\to Y\to Z$ is an exact sequence in $\mathcal{A}$ then 
$$\text{Hom}_R(Z,-)\to\text{Hom}_R(Y,-)\to\text{Hom}_R(X,-)\to0$$
is an exact sequence in $\mathbf{Lex}(\mathcal{A},\hat{\mathcal{B}})$, or in $\mathbf{Lex}(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$ if $X,Y$ and $Z$ are all finitely generated, since if $F$ is another left exact functor then (by Yoneda's lemma) taking maps in $\mathbf{Lex}(\mathcal{A},\hat{\mathcal{B}})$ to $F$ from the sequence gives the exact sequence
$$0\to F(X)\to F(Y)\to F(Z).$$

If we choose $0\to X\to Y\to Z$ so that $Y$ and $Z$ are finitely generated but $X$ is not, and $\text{Hom}_R(X,A)$ has uncountable dimension for some object $A$ of $\mathcal{A}$, then it seems reasonable to hope that there is no cokernel of $\text{Hom}_R(Z,-)\to\text{Hom}_R(Y,-)$ in $\mathbf{Lex}(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$, although there is a cokernel, namely $\text{Hom}_R(X,-)$, in $\mathbf{Lex}(\mathcal{A},\hat{\mathcal{B}})$.

Here's an example where I can prove there is no cokernel. Let $R=S(V)$, the symmetric algebra on a countable dimensional vector space $V$.

Let $J$ be the ideal generated by $V$, and $Y\to Z$ the natural map $R\to R/J$. Then $\text{Hom}_R(J,R/J)$ is uncountable dimensional, being naturally isomorphic to the dual $V^\ast$ of $V$. The cokernel of $\text{Hom}_R(Z-)\to\text{Hom}_R(Y,-)$ in $\mathbf{Lex}(\mathcal{A},\hat{\mathcal{B}})$ is $\text{Hom}_R(J,-)$. Suppose a cokernel $C$ exists in $\mathbf{Lex}(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$. Then there is a natural map
$\text{Hom}_R(J,-)\to C$, the universal map to an object of $\mathbf{Lex}(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$.

For every finite dimensional subspace $U<V$ let $J_U$ be the subideal of $J$ generated by $U$. Then we have natural maps
$$V^\ast\cong\text{Hom}_R(J,R/J)\to C(R/J)\to\text{Hom}_R(J_U,R/J)\cong U^\ast$$
whose composition is the dual of the inclusion $U\to V$.

But for every nonzero element $\varphi\in V^\ast$ there is some finite dimensional subspace $U<V$ so that $\varphi$ is not in the kernel of $V^\ast\to U^\ast$. So $\text{Hom}_R(J,R/J)\to C(R/J)$ must be injective, contradicting the fact that $C(R/J)$ has countable dimension.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, do you think I should ask on MO if there are simpler counterexample?

Comment: @Sov Yes, why not? By the way, here’s another idea I thought about. Is the category of *right* exact functors from a small abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ to $\mathbf{Ab}$ always abelian? If not then left exact functors $\mathcal{A}^{op}\to\mathbf{Ab}^{op}$ won’t form an abelian category. $\mathbf{Ab}^{op}$ isn’t a Grothendieck category because it doesn’t have exact direct limits, and doesn’t satisfy Swan’s conditions because it doesn’t have injective envelopes. It looks as though this won’t work with vector spaces in place of abelian groups, as Swan’s conditions do hold.

Comment: What do you mean by "Swan's condition"?

Comment: @Sov See my comment to the original question. Swan gives a proof assuming that the category of additive functors is cocomplete, well-powered and has injective envelopes (I think that’s equivalent to asking that $\mathcal{B}$ has these properties).

Comment: @Jeremy Rickard No, it is not equivalent, certainly not for a small additive category $\mathcal A$.  Take $k=\mathbb Q$, $\mathcal B$ to be the category opposite to $k$-vector spaces, and $\mathcal A$ to be the category (opposite to) finitely generated free/projective modules over the polynomial ring $k[x]$.  Then the category of additive functors $\mathcal A\to\mathcal B$ is equivalent to the category opposite to $k[x]$-modules.  The ring $k[x]$ is not perfect, so this category of functors does not have injective envelopes.  But the category $\mathcal B$ does.  See also my "answer" below.

Comment: @LeonidPositselski Yes, I was wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is really a comment rather than an answer.  I just wanted to give a link to my answer on MathOverflow https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299014/is-the-category-of-left-exact-functors-abelian , which contains an example showing that the category of left exact functors $\mathcal A^{op}\to (k{-}\mathrm{vect})^{op}$ does not need to be abelian, when $\mathcal A$ is a small (really, small) abelian category and $k{-}\mathrm{vect}$ is the category of vector spaces over a field $k$.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit : this is not the correct answer. However, I decided to let it here because some people thought it was good. Explanations in comments.**

I found a solution here [MathOverflow link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41693/projective-generator-in-the-category-of-left-exact-functors). First I did not understand, so I tried to make it more clear.

Let $\mathcal{A,B}$ be two abelian categories. We want to prove that the category $\mathbf{Lex(\mathcal{A,B})}$ of left exact functors is not abelian. One can check that biproducts, kernels and the zero object still exist. The problem comes from cokernels.

Let us work in $\mathbf{Mod_R}$. We consider the natural transformation $\alpha : Hom(Y,\_) \Rightarrow Hom(X,\_)$ related to a morphism $f:X \rightarrow Y$. One should note that $\alpha$ is nothing more than the natural transformation $Hom(f,\_)$. Let us consider $\beta : Hom(X,\_) \Rightarrow K$ the cokernel of $\alpha$ which is computed pointwise. We want to prove that $K$ does not preserve monomorphisms, which will imply that it is not a left exact functor. For this, let us consider a monomorphism $g:A \rightarrow B$. Then, by naturality we have the following commutative diagram :

Hom(Y,A) \arrow[r,"\alpha_A"] \arrow[d," {Hom(Y,g)} "] & Hom(X,A) \arrow[r,"\beta_A"] \arrow[d," {Hom(X,g)} "] & KA  \arrow[d,"Kg"]  \
Hom(Y,B) \arrow[r,"\alpha_B"] & Hom(X,B) \arrow[r,"\beta_B"] & KB

(sorry I dont know how to do it here, I use tikzcd normally)

Since $KA$ is the cokernel of $\alpha_A$, it is the quotient of $Hom(X,A)$ by the image of $\alpha_A$. In other words, $KA$ is the set of morphisms from $X$ to $A$ which do not factor through $f$. In the same way, $KB$ is the set of morphisms from $X$ to $B$ which do not factors through $f$, and $Kg : v \mapsto g \circ v$. To prove that $K$ does not preserve monomorphisms, we want to find $g$ such that $Kg$ sends a non-zero morphism to zero. For this, we take the ring $R=k[X]$ as a polynomial ring, $X=A$, $Y=B$ and $f=g: (X) \hookrightarrow k[X]$ which a nonsplit monomorphism, i.e. there is no $h:B \rightarrow A$ such that $h\circ f=Id_A$. In this case, the identity $Id_A \in KA$ is a non-zero element but $(Kf)(Id_A)=f$ is a zero-element since it factors through $f$. This proves that $K$ is not left exact and thus the cokernel of $\alpha$ in $\mathbf{Lex(\mathcal{A,B})}$ does not exist in general.

Note : In his thesis, Gabriel proved that under stronger conditions the category $\mathbf{Lex(\mathcal{A,B})}$ is abelian. In fact, if the categories $\mathcal{A,B}$ are abelian and $\mathcal{B}$ has generators and exact inductive limits, then the category $\mathbf{Lex(\mathcal{A,B})}$ is abelian. One particular example which is often used in this thesis (and other works) is the category $\mathbf{Lex(\mathcal{A},Ab)}$.

Comment: This is the third time this incorrect answer has been posted (two others posted then deleted it).  This shows that $\mathbf{Lex(\mathcal{A,B})}$ is not closed under cokernels as a subcategory of the category of all additive functors from $\mathcal{A}$ to $\mathcal{B}$.  It does not show that a cokernel in $\mathbf{Lex(\mathcal{A,B})}$ does not exist.  (Indeed, the fact that $\mathbf{Lex(\mathcal{A},Ab)}$ is abelian directly contradicts your conclusion.)

Comment: Ok thanks ! So the answer on MO is also wrong?

Comment: @Sov No, the answer on MO is to a different question (representable functors are projective in the category of all additive functors, but are they projective in the category of left exact functors? The answer being “no”).

Comment: Ok. Since a lot of people thought this was correct, I think I will let this wrong answer with comments here to make clear that it is not the answer for the future interested readers.